# Insert (random) javascript array item into href

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, href

I have the following code. I would like to make it so that it delivers a href depending on the random array item served (which are the latter parts of the URL). In other words, it should randomly take you to either the Blog (http://website.com/blog), About page or Home page. I have taken note of the method used here: [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array), but they only console log the output. I cannot find any examples of how I would then put that output into the latter part of the href.

```
<a id='link' href='http://website.com/'>Click me</a>

<script>
var pages = ['blog','about','home'];
</script>
```

I expect any answer will use the javascript math.random() function but I have left it out of my question to prevent making it more messy than necessary if I do not use it the most efficiently.

Comment: What have you tried to figure out how to add the randomly selected entry to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get the random index of your array. Once you have the index, you can then grab the value from your array and set the `href` attribute.

```js
const anchor = document.getElementById('link');
const pages = ['blog','about','home'];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length);
anchor.href = `http://website.com/${pages[random]}`;

// For Display Purposes Only
document.getElementById('display').innerText = anchor.href;
```

```html
<a id='link' href='http://website.com/'>Click me</a>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the random element and then reassign the href property of the a tag.

```js
var pages = ['blog','about','home'];
const randomElement = pages[Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length)];

document.querySelector('a').href = `http://${randomElement}.com/`
console.log(document.querySelector('a').href )
```

```html
<a id='link' href='http://website.com/'>Click me</a>
```

Comment: This answer also works perfectly, unfortunately can only pick one.

Comment: So you want use 2?